# Capturing input between periods in Python

Tags: python, regex

How can I capture the numbers between the periods without the periods?

The numbers can be up to but smaller then 3 digits.  0 <= i < 1000

Examples:

- domain.**3**.bumblebee
- domain.**56**.mashabee
- domain.**898**.barista

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use RegEx? If all input strings are of this format it would be better to split and cast the middle value to an int.

Comment: Regexp will look similarly to this: `'\.(\d{1,3})\.'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
your_string.split(".")[1]
```

will give you the number

Example in my ipython shell:-

```
In [47]: your_string = "domain.3.bumblebee"

In [48]: your_string.split(".")[1]
Out[48]: '3'
```

You don't really need regex for your use case.

And of course if you want to return and integer, all you need to do is to cast it.

```
In [49]: int(your_string.split(".")[1])
Out[49]: 3
```

Comment: Not RegEx but actually how you should be doing it. If you want to ensure the int is only three digits add a check `if i < 1000`.

Answer (score 3):

## About Regular Expressions

Regular expressions are not always the solution. There is a quote about using regular expressions.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.
>
> > reference: http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247

## A possible solution using `regex`

1. Use the `re` module for regular expression. Here's [a link to the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html).
2. The match uses a regular expression term of `r"\.(\d{1,3})\."`. This match will find a literal period followed by a number of 1, 2, or 3 digits, followed by another literal period.
3. To assist in the capture of just the digits, use a regex capture group `(...)`. In this case the match for 1, 2, or 3 digits is captured in the parentheses. Here's [a link to some regex examples](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

### Example code for your use case

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> subject = """
... domain.3.bumblebee
... domain.56.mashabee
... domain.898.barista
... """
>>>
>>> matches = re.finditer(r"\.(\d{1,3})\.",subject)
>>> results = [int(match.group(1)) for match in matches]
>>>
>>> results
[3, 56, 898]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'domain.56.mashabee'
>>> mystr = re.compile(r'^\w+\.(\d{1,3})\.')
>>> print mystr.search(str(text)).groups()[0]
56
```